# How to retrieve a users uploaded files using foreign key

Tags: mysql, join, foreign-key, php

I have two tables,users, and,files,

**Users**

Id,firstname,lastname,email,password

**files**

Id,filename,description,userid

Userid in files is foreign key witch relates to Id in users

I am trying to get the users files to show up in his files tab when he logs in

Comment: It would be better if you could put your table structures in as SQL (`SHOW CREATE TABLE blah\G;` it would also be beneficial if you could post sample data - again in the form of SQL! p.s. welcome to the forum! :-) p.p.s. you can find a list of article on how to ask questions here on my profile!

Answer (score 1):

We can help with the SQL, but I'm not a PHP programmer - you'll have to do this yourseslf or go over to StackOverflow! A fiddle is available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0e565ff4ba9c58cb131582474208d726).

Tables:

`user` - note the  use of the singular for table names! Also, note that it is in lower case - for more complex names, use snake_case (this is just my personal preference - if you don't like it, search for "SQL style guide"!

```
CREATE TABLE user 
(
  user_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  firstname VARCHAR (30),
  lastname  VARCHAR (30),
  email     VARCHAR (254),
  password  VARCHAR (64)
);
```

`file` - same logic here as for the singular user table above.

```
CREATE TABLE file
(
  file_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  filename VARCHAR (254) NOT NULL,
  description VARCHAR (254),
  user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT file_user_constraint FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (user_id)
);
```

And the SQL will be:

```
SELECT file_id, filename, description FROM file WHERE user_id = 2;
```

or $my_var where you've fed in 2 - or something like for PHP - as I said, not an expert!

There's some sample data on the fiddle!